# Custom loss with external parameters in Keras Tuner

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, hyperparameters, keras-tuner

While my code runs without any problems with Keras Tuner and standard loss functions like 'mse' I am trying to figure out how to write a custom loss function that accept an external argument in addition to true and forecasted y to use inside Keras Tuner for LSTM model selection. I am looking for the easiest and less painful way and I didn't find a working solution in old posts.

One approach I follewed is this one. Let's say I have these variables

```
# external vector needed in custom loss function
ex_loss= np.logical_not(klines_backtest.loc[i_sel,['d']].to_numpy(dtype=np.float32)[:sample_start])
# create data sequences for x and vector to forecasy y
x_train, y_train = lstm_data_sequence(dataset[:sample_start,:-1], dataset[:sample_start,-1], lstm_sequence)
# concatenate external vector to y so y shape is Nx2
y_train = np.vstack((y_train, ex_loss[lstm_sequence:,0])).T
```

I have defined the following loss function

```
def bande_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    mse = K.square(y_pred - y_true[:,0])
    i_loss = K.equal(y_true[:,1], 1) and K.greater_equal(y_pred, y_true[:,0])
    i_loss = K.cast(~i_loss, 'float32')
    return K.mean(mse*i_loss)
```

Basically I tryied to avoid the loss function override passing the additional variable (of the same size of y_true) I need in the loss function inside y_train where I expext to have y_true and the corresponding external variable correctly sized for the batch.

The LSTM for model selection is

```
def lstm_model(hp):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(InputLayer(input_shape=(48*3, 13)))
    num_layers = hp.Int('num_layers', min_value=4, max_value=8, step=2)
    num_units = hp.Choice('units', values=[50, 100, 250, 500])
    n_dropout = hp.Choice('n_dropout', values=[float(0), 0.10, 0.20])
    n_rec_dropout = hp.Choice('n_rec_dropout', values=[float(0), 0.10, 0.20])
    learning_rate = hp.Choice('learning_rate', values=[1e-2, 1e-3, 1e-4, 1e-5, 1e-6])
    for i in range(num_layers):
        if i < num_layers - 1:
            r_sequence = True
        else:
            r_sequence = False
        model.add(LSTM(
            units=num_units,
            dropout=n_dropout,
            recurrent_dropout=n_rec_dropout,
            return_sequences=r_sequence))

    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.compile(
        optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate),
        loss=bande_loss,
        metrics=[bande_loss])
    return model
```

Executing this code

```
tuner = Hyperband(
    hypermodel=lstm_model,
    objective=Objective("bande_loss", direction="min"),
    max_epochs=50,
    hyperband_iterations=2,
    executions_per_trial=1,
    overwrite=True,
    project_name='hyperband_tuner')
stop_early = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss", patience=3, verbose=1)
tuner.search(x_train, y_train, epochs=30, validation_split=p_train, callbacks=[stop_early],
    shuffle=False, verbose=1)
```

I get this error

```
 The second input must be a scalar, but it has shape [32]
     [[{{node bande_loss/cond/switch_pred/_2736}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_45266]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

Note that 32 is the (default) batch size.

Also running the same code with

```
def bande_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    mse = K.square(y_pred - y_true[:,0])
    return K.mean(mse)
```

seems to work fine while running with

```
def bande_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    mse = K.square(y_pred - y_true[:,1])
    return K.mean(mse)
```

gives me the same error and I cannot understand why.

I also tried the loss function override in this way

```
def lstm_model(hp):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(InputLayer(input_shape=(48*3, 13)))
    num_layers = hp.Int('num_layers', min_value=4, max_value=8, step=2)
    num_units = hp.Choice('units', values=[50, 100, 250, 500])
    n_dropout = hp.Choice('n_dropout', values=[float(0), 0.10, 0.20])
    n_rec_dropout = hp.Choice('n_rec_dropout', values=[float(0), 0.10, 0.20])
    learning_rate = hp.Choice('learning_rate', values=[1e-2, 1e-3, 1e-4, 1e-5, 1e-6])
    for i in range(num_layers):
        if i < num_layers - 1:
            r_sequence = True
        else:
            r_sequence = False
        model.add(LSTM(
            units=num_units,
            dropout=n_dropout,
            recurrent_dropout=n_rec_dropout,
            return_sequences=r_sequence))

    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.compile(
        optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate),
        loss=bande_loss(ex_loss),
        metrics=[bande_loss(ex_loss)])
    return model

def bande_loss(ex_loss):
    def loss(y_true, y_pred):
        mse = K.square(y_pred - y_true)
        i_loss = K.equal(ex_loss, True) and K.greater_equal(y_pred, y_true)
        i_loss = K.cast(~i_loss, 'float32')
        return K.mean(mse*i_loss)
    return loss

...

# external vector needed in custom loss function
ex_loss= np.logical_not(klines_backtest.loc[i_sel,['d']].to_numpy(dtype=np.float32)[:sample_start])
# create data sequences for x and vector to forecasy y
x_train, y_train = lstm_data_sequence(dataset[:sample_start,:-1], dataset[:sample_start,-1], lstm_sequence)
ex_loss = K.variable(ex_loss[lstm_sequence:], dtype=bool)

tuner = Hyperband(
    hypermodel=lstm_model,
    objective=Objective("bande_loss(ex_loss)", direction="min"),
    max_epochs=50,
    hyperband_iterations=2,
    executions_per_trial=1,
    overwrite=True,
    project_name='hyperband_tuner')
stop_early = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss", patience=3, verbose=1)
tuner.search(x_train, y_train, epochs=30, validation_split=p_train, callbacks=[stop_early],
    shuffle=False, verbose=1)
```

But I get this error

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  The second input must be a scalar, but it has shape [4176]
         [[{{node cond/switch_pred/_12}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_34471]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

Can anyone provide me help or a simpler and effective way to implement custom loss functions with external parameters inside Keras Tuner?

Comment: were you able to solve this?

Comment: Yes I did but to be honest I do not remembered the way I followed. I find some hints looking for some similar inquiry here. I cannot give now a reply to my own question even if I find a way because many months have passed. Not sure I still have the code for the custom loss. The main problem are the tensoflows operators you must use inside the loss function, they are not exactly as using numpy operations, you should find a way to make them work with their format and syntax expecially using float and booleans together.

Comment: sounds very complicated. Thanks for the reply